# Sharing a picture on our company's Facebook page with non-friends

Tags: facebook

We have uploaded pictures to our timeline and uploaded pictures to an album and wanted to share the pictures to new customers that we are NOT yet friends with. Is there a way to do this?

If we try to "Share" it will only lets us do that if we know the persons name but I was hoping we could somehow enter the customers email and send them a link to view that design.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually barely not possible. You can only choose Friends or user defined lists to share with or to *not* share with, but you can't choose lists or options for only *non*-friends. You will have to share it with all of your followers, or you can share it as public and then configure it to not be shown to all of your followers, but you'll have to enter them manually (and if after your sharing another person likes he will still see it).